Is there a way to add with 1 click in Windows a video clip at the end of each of thousands of other videos?
Videos are on a folder on a hard drive on a computer for example D:\RobertoVideos\
Looking for a program that can do this.
Writing code is also in consideration if there's no program that does this out of the box.

Does How to extract video from multiple videos with ffmpeg? help? You could write a program to generate the command line - note that there is a limit on the length of the line, somewhere between 8000 and 32767 characters, so you may need to work out some sort of binary division of the work.

Thx, I know only C#, would you please guide me on how to get this project done with ffmpeg, where to learn it and where to run the code?

First, make a directory with some videos in that you can test the actions in so that no videos are lost when you do it for real. I found this Merge videos using FFmpeg concat which is not as complicated as the command line in the Q&A I linked to.

Looking for a program that can do this. it'd have to be specifically written for your needs. I don't know of any program that can do something like that with a single click, just knowing what it is you want to do

Software seeking questions are off-topic. You should ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/unanswered

Code is ok too, regarding Andrew Morton's comment, this is for how to make for multiple videos to turn them into 1 video, what about thousands? that I want to each of them to be added 1 video, so thousands of videos as output, I see the FFmpeg to be the easiest, may this method lose video quality because I want video quality preserved please? this:
$ for f in *.mp4; do echo "file '$f'" >> videos.txt; done
----- and then this:
$ ffmpeg -f concat -i videos.txt -c copy output9.mp4 -------
are for only 1 video as output.

FFMPEG is your friend here. No, we don't recommend code or applications on this site, and you can re-write your question to remove these off topic parts, otherwise your question will be closed here. There are already questions about maintaining quality while using FFMPEG, and questions about iterating through large volumes of files. I recommend that you break down your problem into its component parts and solve each one in turn.
